# Reverse proxy inside OSX application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nginx, reverse-proxy

Is there any reverse proxy that can be embedded within OSX application written in Objective-C? I need to develop application which is going to have reverse proxy embedded inside but not to use an external proxy server instance. Did someone used Nginx that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no reverse proxy written in Objective-C :)
Solution I used is:

- Download nginx source code
- Configure using

```
    ./configure --sbin-path=/usr/local/nginx
       --conf-path=/usr/local/nginx/nginx.conf --pid-path=/usr/local/nginx/nginx.pid --with-http_ssl_module --with-pcre=/usr/local/nginx/src/$PCRE_FILE/ --group=www --user=www --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --prefix=/usr/local/nginx
```

- copy binary into boundle
- run binary using

```
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    NSPipe * out = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput:out];

    [task setLaunchPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/run/nginx", appPath]];
    [task setArguments:@[@"-c", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/conf/nginx/nginx.conf", appPath], @"-p", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/nginx", appPath]]];

    [task launch];
    [task waitUntilExit];
    read = [out fileHandleForReading];
    dataRead = [read readDataToEndOfFile];
    stringRead = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataRead encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"output: %@", stringRead);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's technically possible. I think your idea of using Nginx would work. Why did you call out Objective-C specifically? I don't see why you wouldn't use one written in plain C (there should be no problem with that). You might consider using a separate process space for the proxy, otherwise your app and the proxy might interfere with each other in ways you don't expect. (like calling `exit()`, handling signals, crashing, etc) Then you don't have to figure out how to recompile the proxy inside Xcode, etc - you just have a binary for it and you configure and run it.

The question is, why would you do it? Reverse proxies only make sense when you have a backing server farm to connect to. Do you just need an embedded web server to serve up pages to your application? Why not just use one directly? A reverse proxy would just complicate things.

Comment: I'm asking for Objective-C specifically because of easier embedding. After trying and trying I've compiled and embedded nginx binary inside of app bundle, but I prefer to add it as source inside app to have only one running app instance. If I run (as currently do) nginx as separate process and someone kills it I have a problem.

Comment: I'm doing this because of cross domain issues. In WebView app is loaded and it is making Ajax calls to server but also I need to make http requests to my local http server (embedded inside app) to do some native operations. If I do this I got crossdomain issue. Because of that all requests need to go through one entrance point (proxy) which separate requests to our web server and local http server.

Comment: Why not just have a thread in your app whose job it is to make sure the reverse proxy stays up and running?

Comment: ... or use [cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)?

Comment: I wanted to avoid that :)

Comment: I tried that also, but requests in our case needs to be sync and in that case if operation takes time to complete, interface is frozen.